# Loops and iterations

Tags: algorithm

Is there a way that a function has 2 options of return and the option of return is chosen after a certain interval of iterations?

example:
a function that swaps from "a" to "b" and "b" to "a" after 4 iterations returns:

a
a
a
a
b
b
b
b
a
a
a
a
b
b
b
b
.
.
.

Edit I did something like this to solve the problem:

```js
var counter = 0;
var state = true;

var changeState = function(){
    var x = 0
    while(x != 12){
        if(counter == 4){
            counter = 0;
            state = !state;
        }
        if (state){
           console.log("a");
        } else {
            console.log("b")
        }
        counter += 1;
        x += 1
    }
}

changeState();
```

Comment: Not a "pure" function, but in most programming languages you have state either through global variables, thread static variables, iterators, external databases, or passed in as a parameter, and in that state you can track how many iterations. You may however need to worry about thread safety - what happens if two calls to the function are made at the same time?

Comment: Maybe I'm not getting this.. but what does pure/stateful function has to do with what the OP asks? Why not just to branch two different paths (if-else) of logic and return accordingly? OP mentions *iteration*, not a recursive call. No?

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri, the information on which you would base the `if-else` condition is the state that Ian is referring to.

Comment: @trincot "*and the option of return is chosen after a certain interval of iterations?*" - you probably mean this. I agree, that *if* that *certain interval* is a dynamic given, then it should either be a state member, **or** also can be passed along into function (why not?). I just based my reasoning on the point, that OP does not mention whether the interval is dynamic or not.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri, even if it is not dynamic, you would still need to give the function some state. It must know somehow if it is being executed the first time or not. That is a state requirement.

Comment: I did it. I made a function with 2 states and a counter of how many incrementation. The state changes when the counter is == to a certain number and resets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to have a [stateful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_(computer_science)) function, as it needs to somehow remember something from previous call(s) that were made to it. This is a so-called [side effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)), and means that the function is not [pure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function).

For the example you have given, the function would need to know (i.e. have a state with) the number of previous calls (modulo 8), or the previous four returned values, or some mix of this information.

How such a function is implemented, depends on the programming language.

In object oriented programming languages you would create a class with the function as method, and a property reflecting that state. When the function is called, it also updates the state. For instance, in Java:

```java
class MyClass {
    int callCount = 0;
    char myFunction() {
        return "aaaabbbb".charAt(this.callCount++ % 8);
    }
}
```

You would call the function repeatedly like so:

```java
MyClass obj = new MyClass();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    System.out.println(obj.myFunction());
}
```

In JavaScript you could do the same, or you could create a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)):

```js
function createFunction() {
    let callCount = 0;
    return function myFunction() {
        return "aaaabbbb"[callCount++ % 8];
    }
}

let myFunction = createFunction();
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    console.log(myFunction());
}
```

In Python you can do the same, but it allows also to use default arguments (which are only initialised at function *definition* time), and so you could define an argument that is an object holding a counter:

```py
def myFunction(counter=[0]):
    counter[0] += 1
    return "aaaabbbb"[counter[0] % 8]

for _ in range(10):
    print(myFunction())
```

This is of course not an exhaustive list of possibilities, but the essence is that programming languages offer their own ways to construct such stateful functions.

### Iterators

Some languages offer a different approach: iterators. This means the function produces a stream of return values. The function can run to produce the first value after which the running state is saved until a new value is requested from it. The function's execution context is then restored to run until it can produce the next value, ...etc.

Here is how that design would look in JavaScript:

```js
function * myIterator() {
    let callCount = 0;
    while (true) {
        yield "aaaabbbb"[callCount++ % 8];
    //  ^^^^^ a language construct for yielding back to the caller
    }
}

let iter = myIterator();
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    console.log(iter.next().value);
}
```

When a programming language offers this possibility, it is often preferred over the other alternatives listed earlier.